# post uploaded with FB.api is visible on my timeline, but not on Startpage?

Tags: facebook

When I upload a post with the FB.api javascript it is visible on my timeline but not on the "Startpage" as it is if I post something from within facebook?
Why isnt it visible on the Startpage?

I use the below to post:

> FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
>               method:'stream.publish',
>               source:'http...myimage.jpg',
>               name:'some title',
>               link:'http://www.mydomain.se',
>               description:'some description',
>               message: 'the message....'
>
> ```
>     }, function (response) {
>
>         if (!response || response.error) {
>             alert('Error occured:' + response);
>         } else {
>             alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
>         }
>
>     });
> ```
>
> Thank!

Answer (score 0):

It can be facebook setting. Some of your post can't be visible on start page, maybe because too much other, more "interesting" posts. Try to change on your start page SORT from **Top Stories** to **Most Recent**. It can help, but I am not sure.

If it is visible on your timeline, script code should be ok.